# decoding a JS regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am going through some legacy code and I came across this regular express:

```
var REGEX_STRING_REGEXP = /^\/(.+)\/([a-z]*)$/;
```

I am slightly confused as to what this regular expression signifies.

I have so far concluded the following:

1. Begin with /
2. Then any character (numeric, alphabetic, symbols, spaces)
3. then a forward slash
4. End with alphabetic characters

Can someone advice?

Comment: Your mostly correct; between the slashes there must be at least one character (any character will do). That's what the `+` quantifier means ("one or more"), as opposed to `*` ("zero or more").

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/oqe28ez

Comment: `REGEX_STRING_REGEXP`? The purpose is obvious from name.

Comment: Looks like a regex to match SEO friendly URIs like `/directory_01/` or `/directory_01/file`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool like [Regexper](http://regexper.com) to visualise your regular expressions. If we pass your regular expression into Regexper, we'll be given the following visualisation:

[image: Example]

[**Direct link to Regexper result**](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5C%2F(.%2B)%5C%2F(%5Ba-z%5D*)%24%2F).

Answer (score 1):

regex: /^/(.+)/([a-z]*)$/

^        : anchor regex to start of line

(.+)     : 1 or more instances of word characters, non-word characters, or digits

([a-z]*) : 0 or more instances of any single lowercase character a-z

$        : anchor regex to end of line

In summary, your regular expression is looking to match strings where it is the first  forwardslash, then 1 or more instances of word characters, non-word characters, or digits followed, then another forwardslash, then 0 or more instances of any single lowercase character a-z. Lastly, since both (.+) and ([a-z]*) are surrounded in parenthesis, they will capture whatever matches when you use them to perform regular expression operations.

I would suggest going to [rubular](http://rubular.com/), placing the regex ^/(.+)/([a-z]*)$ in the top field and playing with example strings in the test string box to better understand what strings will fit within that regex. (/string/something for example will work with your regular expression).